# How to show a selected EObject of a JFace TreeViewer in the Eclipse properties view using an Eclipse E4 view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface, e4, eclipse-emf-ecore

I added a TreeViewer to an Eclipse e4 PartDescriptor which contains multiple EMF EObjects. Now I'm having difficulties to show the attributes of the selected TreeItems in the Eclipse properties view.

I already tried the exercise 17 in the tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#adapters_propertyview_example
but couldn't get it to run because the method getAdapter in the Class implementing the IAdapterFactory never gets called. Therefore nothing is displayed in the properties view when a TreeItem is selected. Even though I added the extension point to the plugin as explained in the tutorial.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find more resources which were using an eclipse e4 view.

Is there a way to use the eclipse properties view in an Eclipse e4 view and how is it done?

Comment: The properties view is 3.x compatibility mode code and can't be used in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any other way to show properties in a pure e4 RCP by for example using the tabbed properties view or do I have to create an own view showing the properties?

Comment: e4 provides only the very minimum code. You will have to write your own view.